# AngularFire replacing $id with reference to Object when pushed into array

Tags: angularfire

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here:

```
var eventDetails = new Event(key);

.factory("Event", ["$FirebaseObject", "$firebase",
function($FirebaseObject, $firebase, settings) {

    var EventFactory = $FirebaseObject.$extendFactory({
    });

    return function(eventId) {

        var ref = FIREBASE_REF.child('events/' + eventId);

        var sync = $firebase(ref, {
            objectFactory: EventFactory
        });

        return sync.$asObject(); // this will be an instance of UserFactory
    }
}
])

eventDetails.$loaded(function(){
    eventList.push(eventDetails);
});
```

Every item in eventList is an object with $id = the same object, rather than $id = some string.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you provide a working fiddle/plunkr/etc that demonstrates the behavior? It seems like there must be more at play here.

Comment: Finally figured it out - problem was with a filter I was using that had an obscure piece of code replacing $id with a self reference.